# Ionic ,How to show Multiple tabs,in One templates page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic  ,How to show Multiple tabs,in One templates page?
My demo Is not work.
I want at top and at bottom .

http://codepen.io/TWangCoin/pen/KpLwJe/

```
.state('tabs.sub-tab', {
  url: "/sub-tab",
  views: {
    'sub-tab': {
      templateUrl: "sub-tab.html"
    }
  }
})

.state('tabs.facts', {
  url: "/facts",
  views: {
    'sub-tab': {
      templateUrl: "facts.html"
    }
  }
})
```

main tabs

```
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab">
    </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="sub-tab" icon="ion-ios-search" href="#/tab/sub-tab">
    <ion-nav-view name="sub-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-heart-outline" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
    <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

my sub view

```
<ion-view >
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">tab_view</a>
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

jmp to facts view:

```
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-light tabs-striped tabs-top" delegate-handle="zhiku-tabs">
    <ion-tab title="all">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-content>sss</ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="sends">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-content>sss</ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

run here  come  back allway!
How to Fix it?

Comment: Please reformat your question to include the relevant code in the question, and also better explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I totally understood your question the best way to do this is to statically keep the header and footer and to dynamically change the html according to the click please refer [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/14/deep-linking-a-tabbed-ui-with-angularjs.aspx) link for a kick start and customise it according to your UI need